# Upgrading SVN - Do you need to upgrade the repository or just the working copies?

Tags: svn

I'm using Tortoise SVN and I just upgraded from `V1.6.8` to `1.8.1` and I ran a `svn upgrade` on my working copy; however I'm not sure if I need to run any upgrades on the repository itself!?

I read in another SO post that you didn't need to, but that was talking about `V1.7`, so I wasn't sure it differed between versions or you never need to make upgrades to your repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to upgrade the repository unless you need a new feature that is not available with the older server version (or repository version if using file protocol).

You can find a list of client/server/repository version requirements from the [Apache Subersion](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html) site.

Comment: Thanks. Would you know how to go about upgrading it when needed?

Comment: You can use the [svnadmin upgrade](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.upgrade.html) command to upgrade the repository, or you would need to dump and then load.